# Large block diagrams with auto positioning

Tags: diagrams, automation

I need to make some (large) maintainable block diagrams. Some small diagrams I already made using Tikz, but I always need to specify the placement of every block. Now for large diagrams this could be pretty hard, especially when you add a block in the middle and a lot of directions need to be changed.

Now my question: Is there a package/macro that accepts a bunch of nodes and edges, and arranges them automatically in such a way that edge overlapping is minimal?

Comment: Could you give some examples? Is there a problem using TikZ relative node positioning? If so, what is it?

Comment: When creating a large diagram, you get a lot of white space or overlapping nodes/edges when adding a few new blocks in the middle when using relative positioning. As an example, I found this flow diagram http://www.prince2-basics.com/images/big/conference_flow_diagram.png

Comment: With no example, this is unclear I'm afraid.